# sql query select records that not having

Tags: sql, having

I'm having difficulties to write SQL query
that returns me IDs for which there is no typeA records
for example

```
ID | type
1  | typeA
1  | typeB
1  | typeC
2  | typeB
2  | typeC
3  | typeB
```

this query should return IDs 2 and 3

thanks in advance for any suggestions 
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM   t t1
WHERE  t1.id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT t2.id FROM t t2 WHERE t2.type = 'typeA');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when type = 'TypeA' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

In many databases, you could also use `except`/`minus`:

```
select id
from t
except  -- or minus
select id
from t
where type = 'TypeA';
```